# Symptoms of failed speed sensor code on Nissan Maxima?

Tags: nissan, sensor, maxima

Yesterday morning the check engine light turned on in my 1997 Nissan Maxima, 127K miles, manual transmission.  The mechanic pulled a speed sensor code but it's testing within range now.  I was planning to go on a 2-3 hour drive tomorrow.  If the sensor fails, what would the typical symptoms be?

Comment: This is what I've gathered so far.  Since the car is a manual transmission the speed sensor won't be used for shifting and the speedometer uses a cable, so it should still work too.  I think it will drive the same and the only symptom will be not passing smog.  Here's to hoping I'm right.

Comment: I think you should re-word the question to focus on asking what symptoms and fixes are available.  Asking if the car is OK to drive is off topic.

Comment: @NoCarrier Good idea, question updated.

Comment: Update: The speed sensor remains unfixed with no symptoms.  The check engine light is still on and could be masking other issues, but it's a risk I'm willing to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a failing speed sensor on a truck and the main symptom was the ABS system kicking on between 3-4 mph when I would come to a stop.  It was consistent until I fixed it.  However, it did not throw a check engine light.